# Extjs sync hasOne model on store sync

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, model, associations, has-one

I have two models: first one is **PersonAddress**, which contains info about person and address and second one is **Address**, which contains info about some address.
I connect this to models with *PersonAddress hasOne Address*. Now I have store **PersonAddresses**, which contains few **PersonAddress** models. I want to create new one PersonAddress.

1. I create Address
2. I create PersonAddress
3. I set Address for PersonAddress (personAddress.setAddress(address))
4. Sync PersonAddresses store.

It tryes to create PersonAddress model on the server but my Address model is not created yet.

I want that store PersonAddress while syncing models automatically sync new Address model. Is it possible? It is important, because I use save button on form which contains parent model Person and I want only create Address and PersonAddress when I press save button on Person.

P.S.: Sorry for my English. And you can ask if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think the best way to do this is as I made:

1. I add address field to PersonAddress model and made it persist.
2. When I change address I set address field of PersonAddress and call setDirty() on it.
3. On the server-side I get post data and extract address field.
4. Make/Update my Address model on the server-side.
5. Make/Update my PersonAddress model on the server-side.
6. Connect Address with PersonAddress.